# How to create a variable with error going to /dev/null

Tags: bash, shell, variable-assignment, glob, command-substitution

I am not able to redirect an expected error to &>/dev/null in the following simple code.

```
xml=`ls ./XML_30fps/*.xml ./XML_24fps/*xml`
```

The expected error is due to the fact that one of the folders could be empty and so the error would be "No such file or directory." I don't want this error to show up to the users.

I could resolve this by breaking down this line of code but I was wondering if there was a simple way to redirect to null with a **single line of code** in such case. Neither of these work:

```
xml=`ls ./XML_30fps/*.xml ./XML_24fps/*xml` &>/dev/null
```

```
xml=`ls ./XML_30fps/*.xml ./XML_24fps/*xml &>dev/null`
```

This link [How to avoid printing an error in the console in a BASH script when executing a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244519/how-to-avoid-printing-an-error-in-the-console-in-a-bash-script-when-executing-a) kind of touch upon this but it is not as clear as my question and the answer given here.

Comment: @MaximilianBallard I don't see how this answer my question, but thank you. I am trying to create one variable by listing two folders. If one of the folder is empty, it will give a error. I am trying to get a one-liner that reroutes the error to /dev/null.

Comment: So redirecting error like `xml=\`ls ./XML_30fps/*.xml ./XML_24fps/*xml 2>/dev/null\`` doesn't work?

Comment: `&>/dev/null` will redirect `stdout` AND `stderror` to `/dev/null`  so you are assigning `xml` to nothing.

Comment: @MaximilianBallard Good point! Yes 2>/dev/null works. I didn't see this in the links above.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @MaximilianBallard Could you post your answer with the details above so that I can accept your answer, since it helped me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251484/discussion-between-maximilian-ballard-and-robin).

Comment: If the link I sent in my first comment solved your problem then the question is a duplicate and will probably be removed or closed, etc. Also generally its not good form to answer duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about substituting your command with an alternative that doesn't write to stderr, e.g.

```bash
xml=()
if [ -d XML_24fps ]; then
  xml+=($(find XML_24fps -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.xml'))
fi
if [ -d XML_30fps ]; then
  xml+=($(find XML_30fps -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.xml'))
fi
echo ${xml[@]}
```

In the above, we're using `find` to locate all `*.xml` files in a subfolder. We put a guard condition so that we do not run `find` on folders that do not exist.

By noting that `XML_24fps` and `XML_30fps` are very similar with the difference being just the `24` and `30` we can refactor the above with a `{24,30}` expansion as follows:

```bash
xml=()
for d in XML_{24,30}fps
do
  if [ -d $d ]; then
    xml+=($(find $d -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.xml'))
  fi
done
echo ${xml[@]}
```

Comment: That's nice too

Answer (score 1):

Redirect it within the subshell:

```
xml=`exec 2>/dev/null; ls ./XML_30fps/*.xml ./XML_24fps/*xml`
```

Or

```
xml=$(exec 2>/dev/null; ls ./XML_30fps/*.xml ./XML_24fps/*xml)
```

Comment: Thank you. How do you compare your answer with that of Maximilian xml=`ls ./XML_30fps/*.xml ./XML_24fps/*xml 2>/dev/null` ? Is yours better for some reason? I am not sure why would I need to redirect within the subshell. I would appreciate if you could elaborate.

Comment: @Robin Mine will also capture errors coming from the subshell but it's not necessarily better.